# indexing into a column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to set colb in a pandas array depending on the value in colb. 
The order in which I refer to the two column indices in the array seems to have an impact on whether the indexing works. Why is this?

Here is an example of what I mean.

I set up my dataframe:

```
test=pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(20,1))
test['cola']=[x for x in range(20)]
test['colb']=0
```

If I try to set column b using the following code:

```
test.loc['colb',test.cola>2]=1
```

I get the error:`ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence

If I use the following code, the code alters the dataframe as I expect.

```
test.loc[test.cola>2,'colb']=1
```

Why is this?

Further, is there a better way to assign a column using a test like this?

Comment: As for *why*, it's because `myobj[a, b]` is the pretty way to say `myobj.__getitem__((a, b))` (`__setitem__` if you're assigning) and `myobj[b, a]` is `myobj.__getitem__((b, a))`. If [the magic method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getitem__) cares about order, then it will change the behavior.

Comment: Is this how the loc method of a pandas dataframe is implemented? Do you have any suggestions of where I could find this is described? Thanks.

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#indexing-view-versus-copy

Comment: @Landmaster That section doesn't mention anything about the order of the column titles. Also, the example there (dfmi.loc[:,('one','second')] = value) doesn't allow for conditional indexing (e.g. my use of >). What am I misunderstanding here?

Comment: The bare colon often means "everything" (Python translates it to `slice(None, None, None)`), but if you pass a boolean array/series, that will get handled sensibly as well. It does because it was designed that way, and it seems to work for you. Not happy?

Comment: Coming back to this I see better what's going on. test.cola>2 is defining the rows and 'colb' the columns to refer to. Sorry, I was just confused somehow before. Thanks.